# Using Vulkan occlusion queries to inform future rendering decisions?

Tags: vulkan

In the Vulkan spec section 17.3 (Queries > Occlusion Queries) it says:

> Occlusion queries track the number of samples that pass the per-fragment tests for a set of drawing commands.  The application can then use these results to inform future rendering decisions.

In what way would you use the number of samples that pass the fragment tests to inform future rendering decisions?

What's an example of such a rendering decision that would use the result of an occlusion query?

Comment: You mean, besides the obvious case of not rendering things that are occluded?

Comment: @NicolBolas: No, not beside that.